# How to update data in database without removing the old data?

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to know how this can be done. lets say i have this in my database "first" and if i want to update and add the "second" in which i can have this format "first, second".
i used this `UPDATE table SET number="second"` but it removes the "first".
i am using php and mysql,
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean:

```
// if number is "first", it will become "first, second"
UPDATE table SET number = CONCAT(number, ", second")
```

but I don't think that's what you need. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: FWIW: if you're trying to store a list in a database, don't do it this way. Instead store the data as separate rows and use GROUP_CONCAT to extract the result when you do a select.

Comment: Why using a database if storing several Items in one column of all rows? I don't see any sense in the statements of both answers. As Tatu allready mentioned: please explain your question in more details.

Comment: all im trying to do is i want to store some names (maximum of 5) in a same category and then use explode(', ', $names); and show them using "for" loop. u guys think this is not a good method?

Comment: Well, according to how databased *should* be designed, the names should be in their own table with a reference to entry in a another table they relate to.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET number=concat_ws(",", number, "second")
```

Comment: This is actually "first,second" and not "first, second".

Comment: you can easily just add a space after the , in the function call

Answer (score 0):

The update answer you've chosen gives you what you want. I want to chime in with somethings that you may find useful.

Since you are obviously learning, let's ensure that you get some related items covered as well:

1. **Database and Code Backup:** Keep the original safe before you start having your fun with it. If something goes wrong, you can always restore from backup and move on.
2. **Souce Code Control**: Keep your code under Source Code Control so that you can go back to previous versions as and when required.
3. **Separation of Prod and Dev**: If you play in Production, you have the ability to cause a lot of damage. Make double triple sure that you are working in an isolated environment.